# How to display item in multiple column with ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have item list view which consist image,text and button.I am trying to display those item in 2 column and multiple rows.I am using custom adapter to achieve this but unfortunately all item come in single column only.Please see the wireframe for more clarity about my question.
[wireframe for my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhTdy.png)

Comment: GridView? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: use `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **RecyclerView** with **GridLayourManager**.

```
final int ROWSCOUNT = 2;
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), ROWSCOUNT, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclewView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Here is [RecycleView docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)